# VB.NET An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'

Tags: vb.net, datasource

I am developing a VB.NET ASPX file and am trying to run a string query in VB.NET, but now I get the above error message.  How can I determine the cause?  Some of the code in this ASPX file is below.  The line it errors on is:
DSPageData = GlobalFunctions.GlobalF.GetSQLServerDataSet(SQL)

But this same function works for one of my other SQL strings, so I think the problem is somewhere in this SQL string:

```
            arrType.Add("Product and Process")
            arrType.Add("Product")
            arrType.Add("Process")                          
            dType.DataSource = arrType
            dType.DataBind()

                arrPEType.Add("INC")
                arrPEType.Add("NC")
                arrPEType.Add("QC")
                peType.DataSource = arrPEType
                peType.DataBind()
...
        Select Case dType.SelectedValue
            Case "Product and Process": 
                TheType = "(SMARTSOLVE.V_QXP_ALL_EXCEPTION.QXP_BASE_EXCEPTION='PXP_PRODUCT_QXP' Or SMARTSOLVE.V_QXP_ALL_EXCEPTION.QXP_BASE_EXCEPTION)='PXP_PROCESS_QXP')"
            Case "Product": 
                TheType = "(SMARTSOLVE.V_QXP_ALL_EXCEPTION.QXP_BASE_EXCEPTION='PXP_PRODUCT_QXP')"
            Case "Process": 
                TheType = "(SMARTSOLVE.V_QXP_ALL_EXCEPTION.QXP_BASE_EXCEPTION='PXP_PROCESS_QXP')"
        End Select

            Select Case peType.SelectedValue
                Case "INC": 
                    PE_Type = "(substring(a.QXP_EXCEPTION_NO, charindex('-', a.QXP_EXCEPTION_NO)+1, 4)='INC')"
                Case "NC": 
                    PE_Type = "(substring(a.QXP_EXCEPTION_NO, charindex('-', a.QXP_EXCEPTION_NO)+1, 4)='NC')"
                Case "QC": 
                    PE_Type = "(substring(a.QXP_EXCEPTION_NO, charindex('-', a.QXP_EXCEPTION_NO)+1, 4)='QC')"
            End Select

            If dOrgUnit.SelectedValue = "All" then
                TheOrgUnit = "<> 'All'"
            Else
                TheOrgUnit = "='" & dOrgUnit.SelectedValue & "'"
            End If

            Dim SQL As String = "SELECT CASE SMARTSOLVE.V_QXP_ALL_EXCEPTION.QXP_BASE_EXCEPTION WHEN 'PXP_PROCESS_QXP' THEN SMARTSOLVE.V_QXP_ALL_EXCEPTION.QXP_SHORT_DESC ELSE EPF_FAILURE_MODE END AS QXP_SHORT_DESC, " & _
                                "Count(distinct SMARTSOLVE.V_QXP_ALL_EXCEPTION.QXP_EXCEPTION_NO) AS CountOfQXP_EXCEPTION_NO " & _
                                 "FROM SMARTSOLVE.V_QXP_ALL_EXCEPTION LEFT OUTER JOIN " & _
                                    "SMARTSOLVE.V_EPL_EXCEPTION_PART_LOT ON V_QXP_ALL_EXCEPTION.QXP_ID = V_EPL_EXCEPTION_PART_LOT.EPL_QXP_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN " & _
                                    "SMARTSOLVE.V_EPF_EXPN_PART_FMODE ON V_EPL_EXCEPTION_PART_LOT.EPL_EPA_ID = V_EPF_EXPN_PART_FMODE.EPF_EPA_ID " & _
                                    "LEFT OUTER JOIN SMARTSOLVE.V_PXP_PRODUCT_QXP ON SMARTSOLVE.V_QXP_ALL_EXCEPTION.QXP_ID = SMARTSOLVE.V_PXP_PRODUCT_QXP.QXP_ID " & _
                                          "LEFT OUTER JOIN SMARTSOLVE.V_PXP_PROCESS_QXP ON SMARTSOLVE.V_QXP_ALL_EXCEPTION.QXP_ID = SMARTSOLVE.V_PXP_PROCESS_QXP.QXP_ID " & _
   "WHERE SMARTSOLVE.V_QXP_ALL_EXCEPTION.QXP_OCCURENCE_DATE >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '" & FirstMonthDate & " 00:00:00', 102) " & _
   "And SMARTSOLVE.V_QXP_ALL_EXCEPTION.QXP_OCCURENCE_DATE <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '" & LastMonthDate & " 23:59:59', 102) AND " & _
   "SMARTSOLVE.V_QXP_ALL_EXCEPTION.QXP_XRS_DESCRIPTION<>'Cancel' AND " & _
   "SMARTSOLVE.V_QXP_ALL_EXCEPTION.QXP_ORU_NAME" & TheOrgUnit & _
   " and " & TheType & _
   "AND (CASE V_QXP_ALL_EXCEPTION.QXP_BASE_EXCEPTION WHEN 'PXP_PROCESS_QXP' THEN V_PXP_PROCESS_QXP.PXP_OPR_NAME ELSE V_PXP_PRODUCT_QXP.PXP_OPR_NAME END <> 'Non-Diagnostic' OR " & _
                                    "CASE V_QXP_ALL_EXCEPTION.QXP_BASE_EXCEPTION WHEN 'PXP_PROCESS_QXP' THEN V_PXP_PROCESS_QXP.PXP_OPR_NAME ELSE V_PXP_PRODUCT_QXP.PXP_OPR_NAME END IS NULL) " & _
                                 "GROUP BY CASE SMARTSOLVE.V_QXP_ALL_EXCEPTION.QXP_BASE_EXCEPTION WHEN 'PXP_PROCESS_QXP' THEN SMARTSOLVE.V_QXP_ALL_EXCEPTION.QXP_SHORT_DESC ELSE EPF_FAILURE_MODE END " & _
                                 "ORDER BY Count(distinct SMARTSOLVE.V_QXP_ALL_EXCEPTION.QXP_EXCEPTION_NO) DESC"

            Dim DSPageData as new System.Data.DataSet
            DSPageData = GlobalFunctions.GlobalF.GetSQLServerDataSet(SQL)
```

Comment: The error is very likely to be in the SQL command.  Can you format that command in a readable manner?  It could be something as simple as an unmatched parenthesis.

Comment: ***DO NOT USE STRING CONCATENATION LIKE THAT TO SUBSTITUTE PARAMETERS INTO YOUR QUIERIES!!*** Yes, I do mean to shout.  This is a _huge_ problem.  Go read up on sql injection before doing anything else.

Comment: And I hate to say it, but from the look of things you will have to re-architect your whole data layer so the GetSQLServerDataSet() function can accept more than just a string parameter for queries.  _This is that important_.  If you don't do this and you put your page on the public internet, it _will_ be hacked in the first two years.  I can promise you that.

Comment: Good point Joel, but this file will only run on the intranet

Comment: sql injection holes are still bad and should be plugged. After all, most hacks are inside jobs.  Running it on the intranet is not an excuse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one too many ) here:

```
           Case "Product and Process"                 
TheType = "(SMARTSOLVE.V_QXP_ALL_EXCEPTION.QXP_BASE_EXCEPTION='PXP_PRODUCT_QXP' Or SMARTSOLVE.V_QXP_ALL_EXCEPTION.QXP_BASE_EXCEPTION)='PXP_PROCESS_QXP')"
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `" and " & TheType & _` in you code above should be replace with:
 `" and " & PE_Type & _`.

I really hope this doesn't mean you're running with Option Explicit turned off.  For shame.

But please take my comments on sql injection to heart.  There are people out there running software that randomly trolls web sites looking for vulnerable pages, and even if you don't have a plain text input I could craft an http request that would submit anything I wanted via the dOrgUnit dropdown list.  Including something like: `='1';DROP Table SMARTSOLVE.V_QXP_ALL_EXCEPTION;--`

Comment: Thanks but no that's not the problem. See my updated description

Comment: @user - the next debugging step then is to log the sql string somewhere so you can paste it directly into sql server management studio and see what the results are.